# How to manage a buffer between C and C#

Tags: c#, xcode, memory-management, interop, unity-game-engine

### Problem

I have a C# script that calls C functions via System.Runtime.Interop. I managed to invoke C functions, but I have problem managing a buffer between C and C#.

In my situation C is the (data) producer and C# is the consumer.

My problem is when I read data in C#, sometime I get the correct value but sometimes I get NULL.

This problem is already solved. I am pasting my wrong approach AND my right approach here to share with you.

### Background

**The C# code is a unity script(part of Mono development), and the C code is in Xcode, which means I cannot use .Net framework functions in my C code.**

### Wrong approach (gives me NULL from time to time)

Here is my C code (write to buffer and read from buffer):

```
static char InteropBF[INTEROP_BUFFER_SIZE];
static int mutex = 0;
// for the c code to put its message in buffer
void PutToBuffer(char* name, char* content)
{
    while (mutex>0);
    mutex++;
    strcat(InteropBF, name);
    strcat(InteropBF, ",");
    strcat(InteropBF, content);
    strcat(InteropBF, ",");
    printf("Interop Buffer: %s\n", InteropBF);
    mutex--;
}


// for the C# code to poll and read from C
void* ReadFromBuffer(void* temp)
{
    while (mutex>0);
    mutex++;
    strcpy(temp, InteropBF);
    // memcpy(temp, InteropBF, INTEROP_BUFFER_SIZE);
    strcpy(InteropBF, "");
    mutex--;
    return temp;
}
```

I exposed the function ReadFromBuffer() to C#:

```
[DllImport ("CCNxPlugin")]
public static extern IntPtr ReadFromBuffer(IntPtr temp);
```

Then, I call the function like this:

```
        IntPtr temp = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(8912);
        CCN.ReadFromBuffer(temp);
        string news = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(temp);
        if(news != "")
        {
            print (news);
        }
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(temp);
```

Using this code I sometimes get the correct buffer content but more frequently I get a NULL from the Marshal.PtrToStringAuto function.

### Right Approach (Many thanks to you all!)

I'd like to paste my working code and references I found here --

C function:

```
struct bufnode
{
    char* name;
    char* content;
    struct bufnode *next;
};

struct bufnode* bufhead = NULL;
struct bufnode* buftail = NULL;
// for the c code to put its message in buffer
void PutToBuffer(char* name, char* content)
{
    struct bufnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct bufnode));
    temp->name = malloc(256);
    temp->content = malloc(256);
    strcpy(temp->name,name);
    strcpy(temp->content,content);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (bufhead == NULL && buftail == NULL) {
        bufhead = temp;
        buftail = temp;
    }
    else if(bufhead != NULL && buftail != NULL){
        buftail->next = temp;
        buftail = temp;
    }
    else {
        printf("Put to buffer error.\n");
    }    
}

// for the C# code to poll and read from C
struct bufnode* ReadFromBuffer()
{
    if (bufhead != NULL && buftail != NULL) {
        // temp->name = bufhead->name;
        // temp->content = bufhead->content;
        // temp->next = NULL;
        struct bufnode* temp = bufhead;
        if (bufhead == buftail) {
            bufhead = NULL;
            buftail = NULL;
        }
        else {
            bufhead = bufhead->next;
        }

        return temp;
    }
    else if(bufhead == NULL && buftail == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

C# wrapper:

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct bufnode 
{
    public string name;
        public string content;
        public IntPtr next;
}


[DllImport ("CCNxPlugin")]
public static extern IntPtr ReadFromBuffer();
```

Calling function in C#:

```
        CCN.bufnode BufNode;
        BufNode.name = "";
        BufNode.content = "";
        BufNode.next = IntPtr.Zero;

        IntPtr temp = CCN.ReadFromBuffer();
        if(temp != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            BufNode = (CCN.bufnode)Marshal.PtrToStructure(temp, typeof(CCN.bufnode));
            print(BufNode.name);
            print(BufNode.content);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(temp);
        }
```

### Summary

1. char[] does not seem like a good buffer between C and C# (at least in my case where I am using Unity-Mono and Xcode). My suggestion is to organize data in a struct and pass the struct as parameter or as return value to C#. I've found great documentation about passing classes and structures but I haven't found any about passing char array just by itself. So I guess it is always better to wrap a char[] in a struct or in a class.
2. A C struct can be marshaled as a C# class or a C# struct. Passing a wrapping **class** to unmanaged function as a parameter will work. Passing a wrapping **struct** to unmanaged function as a parameter will also work. Returning a pointer to a **struct** from unmanaged function is okay. Returning a pointer to a **class** from unmanaged function is **NOT** okay. (Found a great tutorial about this: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Summary)

Comment: Please post both the relevant C and C# code.

Comment: yep, too general, could be anything really

Comment: @vcsjones Sorry about that, I just edited it and posted my code

Comment: you might want to look at better ways for thread synchronization.  Looping until mutex larger than 0 will use 100% of a CPU until mutex is larger than 0.  If you had one CPU, you're likely going to appear to hang.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thanks Peter, this is just an early demo so I was very concerned about getting the correct result. I think after I get the right buffer value I will definitely use other ways than busy waiting. For now I just find it very easy to code :)

Comment: @PeterRitchie I changed the code to the best of my capability but I am still getting Null from time to time... I was assuming if memory is allocated in managed code and then passed to unmanaged code then it should work fine, right?

Comment: You do know that mutex++ and mutex-- aren't necessarily atomic right?

Comment: in x86 and x64 ++ and -- are atomic...  To support other CPUs use Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.Decrement

Comment: +1 for bothering to return to your question, tidying it up & showing your final solution for interested others ;)

Comment: @violet313 I cleaned it up a little bit, hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing back a stack variable.  That variable can be "collected" or freed in C/C++ upon return from the method--which will randomly result in bad memory by the time it gets to PtrToStringAuto.  This would explain why it's *sometimes* null.  You need to allocate memory that is passed back to the C# code and that code needs to free the memory (or the C/C++ needs to do it somehow).

You can do that in c/c++ with CoTaskMemAlloc and in C#, free it with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem.

Comment: Thanks! So my InteropBF[] is being freed? Or the temp[] in ReadFromBuffer() is being freed? Or both?

Comment: temp is being freed (well, it's more like it's being re-used)

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try CoTaskMemAlloc with temp and get it back to you later!

Comment: No no, I simpley can't do it. I can't call CoTaskMemAlloc. Maybe it's because I am using Xcode? Can I use .Net framework in Xcode? Or is there a work around?

Comment: XCode?  Is the C# part being done in Mono?  That would have been really useful information to have included with your question...

Comment: Yes the C# part is a Unity script, which uses Mono framework. I just edited my question, sorry about the confusion and thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

try passing in a c# string type and using `SysAllocString` from within the C++ :

```
// for the C# code to poll and read from C
void ReadFromBuffer(BSTR* pstrRet)
{
    while (mutex>0);
    mutex++;

    *pstrRet=SysAllocString(InteropBF)

    strcpy(InteropBF, "");
    mutex--;
}

//calling from c# 
string news ="";
ReadFromBuffer(out news);
if(news != "")
{
    print (news);
}
```

Otherwise you could try creating a byte array of sufficient size for your return value in c# & passing the underlying pointer to memory to your xcode. like this:

```
// for the C# code to poll and read from C
unsigned int ReadFromBuffer(char* pstrRet, unsigned int cbSize)
{
    unsigned int uiRet;

    while (mutex>0);
    mutex++;

    uiRet=strlen(InteropBF);

    if (uiRet > 0 && cbSize > uiRet) 
    {    
        strcpy(pstrRet, InteropBF);
    }
    else //error
    {        
        uiRet=0;
    }

    strcpy(InteropBF, "");
    mutex--;

    return uiRet;
}


//calling from c# 
[DllImport ("CCNxPlugin")]
public static extern UInt32 ReadFromBuffer(IntPtr pData, UInt32 cbData);
.
.
. 

String news;
UInt32 cbData=INTEROP_BUFFER_SIZE; //you need to define this in c# ;)
Byte[]  abyData=new byte[cbData];

try
{     
    //kindly request GC gives us a data address & leaves this memory alone for a bit
    GCHandle oGCHData = GCHandle.Alloc(abyData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pbyData = oGCHData.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    UInt32 cbCopied=ReadFromBuffer(pbyData, cbData);

    oGCHData.Free();

    if(cbCopied > 0)
    { 
        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        news = enc.GetString(abyData,0,cbCopied);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks! the tricky thing is I am using Xcode and I find it a little hard to use .Net functions in it. I can use .Net functions in C# though. I am trying to look for similar functions from the Cocoa framework, please let me know if you have a recommendation.

Comment: ah. you might want to include that fact in your question & maybe add an xcode tag ;) ~i added another way that may work for you -i'm not sure it's the best approach..